# (Java) Ler TXT (input) e gerar TXT (output) com as informações organizadas

Tags: java, lógica, nullpointerexception

Preciso montar a seguinte lógica:
1- Ler um txt com várias linhas, cada linha possui uma atividade EX: Caminhar 10min, Estudar 30min... (cada atividade em uma linha).
2- Meio dia horário de almoço.
3- Organizar as atividade por tempo que cada uma leva para ser executada, antes e pós almoço.
4- Grava o txt de saída com as informações organizas.

> Meu código até agora

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

        String nomePc = System.getProperty("user.name");
        String path = "C:\\Users\\" + nomePc + "\\Desktop\\input.txt";
        String outputDir = "C:\\Users\\" + nomePc + "\\Desktop\\output.txt";

        FileReader arq = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        String linha = lerArq.readLine();

        //Output   
        File file2 = new File(outputDir);
        FileWriter arq_output = new FileWriter(file2, true);
        PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq_output);

        if (!file2.exists()) {
            // Como o arquivo não existe, cria um novo arquivo
            file2.createNewFile();
        }

        while (linha != null) {

           linha = lerArq.readLine();

            System.out.println(linha);
            String trinta_min = "30min";
            linha.toLowerCase().contains(trinta_min.toLowerCase());

        }
        lerArq.close();
        gravarArq.close();
        arq.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.printf("Erro ao localizar o arquivo: %s.", e.getMessage());

    };
}
```

> **Dúvida**: Se eu uso a variável `linhas`para rastrear o valor de cada atividade com ideia de retornar `true` ou `false` dá erro (`at xxxxx.xxxxx.main(null xxxx.java:63)`) e (`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`).

```
String trinta_min = "30min";
linha.toLowerCase().contains(trinta_min.toLowerCase()));
```

Caso alguém tenha sugestão de outras maneiras, também é aceitável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode testar se a linha é nula antes de chamar `linha.toLowerCase()`.

```
    while (linha != null) {

       linha = lerArq.readLine();

        System.out.println(linha);
        String trinta_min = "30min";

        boolean sao30min = false;
        if (linha != null) {
            sao30min = linha.toLowerCase().contains(trinta_min.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
```

Obs.: Podem ser do seu interesse os métodos:

- [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset));
- [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), entre outros de String, como o `endsWith()`.